# Novice needs help with slicing section off a tapered cue

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to design a snooker cue & I'm finding it tricky to slice a section from the butt of the cue to give a flat edge about 6" length. I've marked where I want the slice on the picture with a yellow line. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why not use a curve instead of a mesh ? That way you can easily set the tapering and beveling curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways I might do this:

- Using the KNIFE tool with Cut-Through enabled (K, then Z) to slice through the mesh at your desired angle. Though note this is likely to result in Tri's or Ngon faces, which might not work well if you have a subsurf on the mesh.
  [image]
- Select the faces you need to flatten and use the 'Flatten' command (press space, search flatten) - then rotate the selection or use proportional editing to move the flattened faces to the desired angle.

[image]

Hope this helps!